# get current browser latitude and longitude values and display it in another

Tags: javascript

i am trying to get the location of a device to show it through my web page using react.I need a solution from react or JavaScript using any library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position)=> {
  console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
  console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
}
```

using javascript
It will ask for permission to access location we can only get once we allow access.